# What should I put in redirect_uri when sending to FB if I want nothing to happen?

Tags: android, facebook, uri

I have managed to get my Android application to post to FB (at last).
However, I am stuck on what exactly I am meant to put in the field "redirect_uri".

I don't want to do anything special whether the user clicked post or not. 
Is there a way I can just simply ignore it?

Would love to be able to leave it out but it is a compulsory parameter.

Update:

In order to be able to post I created a dummy application in FB. Maybe that's where I went wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave out the redirect_uri, it will be automatically filled in by most of the SDKs, I'm not sure if that's definitely true of the Android SDK. You could just use the current URL in that field, meaning the user won't go anywhere?

Comment: Problem is that FB insists I put in the URI that is defined for application within FB. Since the URI in FB is defined as http://www.anykey.co.il/yaniv it insists I put in at least redirect_uri=http://www.anykey.co.il/yaniv.

Comment: Sure, but what I meant was - could you not just let the redirect_uri always be the current URL that the user was on before they clicked the 'share' or 'post' button?

Comment: Thing is I am sending it from the phone using FB feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/